# How to let Dart run a separate process in a server?

Tags: dart

For example, here is a simple dart code:

```
#import('dart:io');

main() {
  var server = new HttpServer();
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);
  server.defaultRequestHandler = (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
    response.outputStream.write('Hello, world'.charCodes());
    response.outputStream.close();
  };
}
```

when the web server print the 'Hello, world', I would like to run a progress to run a 
long heavy task, but don't want to it blocking the current process. May I know how to handle it? Thanks.

I tried with `Process.run` and `Process.start` with no success.

Comment: Can you show how you have tried to use `Process.run` and `Process.start`? It should work but maybe you have done something wrong.

Comment: Process.start('dart', ['./lib/src/service/AnalysisFile.dart', '&']); //fail, after my process end. 

Process.runSync('dart', ['./lib/src/service/AnalysisFile.dart', '&'], runInShell: true); //ok.

Answer (score 1):

From you comment I can tell there are a misunderstanding of how Dart works spawning external processes. When you spawn a process in Dart it is by default running so the Dart program and the external program are running separate (so in different processes) and the Dart program can execute other stuff. You can then await for the result from the program (e.g. when it closes).

Therefore it does not make much sense to run the process with "&" as parameter (I guess this was an attempt to tell it should run separately from the Dart program).

But, since you are spawning another Dart program your should also consider using an Isolate which can execute both your own method on another thread or run external code by using:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawnUri.html